# asp.net mvc app_data folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to store a large number of images on a server gallery. I can create my own folder for that, but in the default template there is a folder named App_Data. Obviously, I imagine that creators of the template meant for us to store data there. But I can't find a way to open anything in that folder.

Is it intended? Or how do I do that? Or should I make my own folder for that reason?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is by design.  App_Data was meant for data files like sql express DB's files.  It is protected so that you can't surf to it and grab files out of it.  Put your images in another folder to correct this.

Comment: what kind of data can be stored in app_data ? should i use this app_data only to store sql related files?

Comment: It can hold anything you want.  Generally, it has been used for local database files such as SQL Express & SQLLite.  If you have an xml file and/or json file you can store it there as well.  App_Data is just protected by .Net to not allow direct access.  You can put any file you want in there that you want protected in this manner.